# Present participle

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, grammaticality, continuous-aspect, get-passive

Is possible to say "bored" in present participle?
How I understand it is past participle.

I want to say "I am seeing, how she is feeling bored at the lesson now." and I want to use present continuous. 
Only I want to use one word instead of "feeling bored".

Comment: "I can see that she is bored with the lesson now".

Comment: Sorry, I didn't say. I want to say this phrase in present continuous. Your phrase is simple, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Bored* is historically a past participle, but most of the time it is an adjective, and is not tensed. So "she is bored" is fine.

I think you are looking for a verb meaning "be bored", and I don't think there is one.

Comment: In principle, I thought so. I just wanted to make sure. And if I say "I am being bored". Is so correctly? I want to say this phrase in present continuous.

Comment: You can say *I am getting bored*. See the comparison with *I am being bored*. (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+am+getting+bored%2C+I+am+being+bored&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20am%20getting%20bored%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20am%20being%20bored%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @JuniorL I read *I am being bored* and immediately thought of it in the *I am being drilled* sense. ;) (That meaning, incidentally, is perfectly fine with the verb tense.)

Comment: _I am being bored_ is grammatical, but it's hard to think of circumstances in which anybody would say it. It is synonymous with _[someone] is boring me_, but with the focus that comes with a passive.

Comment: @ColinFine Do you want to say _He is boring me._ is equal _I am bored by him._?

Comment: @JasonBassford Yeap, this sense is interesting. :) What do you mean -  verb tense?

Comment: @JuniorL I mean the "drilled" sense of *bored* works just fine with *Help, I am being bored!* (somebody is drilling a hole in me), even if the "I've lost interest" sense of the word doesn't necessarily.